# How can I replicate this SQL within SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, gis

I need to replicate the following SQL statement in SQLAlchemy, I use the ORM, and although I could just use the raw engine to run the SQL I then loose the object oriented goodness in the results.

```
SELECT *, 
  (6371 * acos(cos(radians(50.4)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(-4.15)) + sin(radians(50.4)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) distance 
FROM mapobject 
HAVING distance < 150
ORDER BY distance;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright in the end I conceded that this is a lot easier using the engine inside of the session directly and loosing out on the ORM goodness for this one query and hence...

```
    sql = text('SELECT *, (6371 *acos(cos( radians( %s ) ) * cos( radians( `latitude` ) ) * cos(radians( `longitude` ) - radians( %s )) + sin(radians(%s)) * sin(radians(`latitude`)))) `distance` FROM `mapobject` JOIN user ON mapobject.created_by = user.id WHERE deleted=0 HAVING `distance` < %s ORDER BY `distance`;' % (latitude, longitude, latitude, distance))
    map_objects = g.db.connection().execute(sql)
    humanised_map_objects = []
    for map_object in map_objects:
        tags = g.db.query(MapObjectTag).filter(MapObjectTag.map_object_id == map_object[0]).all()
        text_tags = []
        for tag in tags:
            text_tags.append(tag.tag)

        map_object_humanised = {'id': map_object[0],
                                'object_type': map_object[1],
                                'longitude': map_object[3],
                                'latitude': map_object[2],
                                'description': map_object[6],
                                'created_at': map_object[5].isoformat(),
                                'created_by': map_object[9],
                                'tags': text_tags}
        humanised_map_objects.append(map_object_humanised)
```

however as always if someone has a better way todo this and still have the ORM goodness let me know.